# Desactivar evento cellendedit datagridview

Tags: c#, datagrid

Tengo un `DataGridView` que me obtiene valores de una tabla `SQL Server`, selecciono un producto y al darle `click` a la siguiente celda, me obtiene su precio, esto se genera con el evento `CellEndEdit`, pero requiero cambiar el valor del precio manualmente.

¿Cómo desactivo ese evento para que pueda ingresar el nuevo precio, se puede?

Lo deseo hacer con un `CheckBoxColumn` cuando este seleccionado que me deje editar y cuando no, no se podrá por fila o como podría funcionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponga lo siguiente:

En su `DataGridView` la primera columna es la tipo `CheckBoxColumn` por lo cual será la `index = 0;` y la columna 3 es la del `Precio` en el evento `CellValueChanged` de su `DataGridView` puede hacer algo como esto:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        object value = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        if (value == true) 
        {
            DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].ReadOnly = true;
        } else 
        {
            DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].ReadOnly = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Si esto le produce alguna excepción:

```
object value = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
if (value == true)
```

También puede hacerlo así:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value) == true)
```

> Con esto **no** esta desactivando el evento `CellEndEdit` como tal, lo que esta haciendo es la celda `Precio` que desea modificar sea o no editable.

Comment: Rodriguez Pero el problema que si la puedo editar solo que se ejecuta el evento y me vuelve a obtener el precio de la base de datos.

Comment: @JavierBarrera no entiendo cuando dice que se ejecuta el evento, ya que el evento `CellEndEdit` se ejecuta únicamente cuando se modifica la celda, de otra manera no se ejecutará, a que se refiere? explique mejor por favor

Comment: J.Rodríguez esque mi evento se ejecuta al editar cualquier celda tengo que ponerlo que se ejecute solo en una celda como lo podria hacer.

Comment: J.Rodriguez Ya quedo solo asigne el evento al comboboxcolumn esque lo manejaba para todas las celdas, gracias.

Comment: J.Rodriguez Ya quedo solo asigne el evento al comboboxcolumn esque lo manejaba para todas las celdas, gracias.

Comment: @JavierBarrera Ok, si mi respuesta le ha sido de ayuda no olvide marcar como valida. Saludos!